# c++ code behaves differently within Linux than Windows?

Tags: c++

I recently moved from windows to linux i was used to learn c++ with Visual-studio,
now i try to write something in linux and it behaves different for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomainip>

int main(){
char a {'a'};
char* b { &a };
size_t count {16};

for(size_t i{};i < count;i++){
    std::cout << std::hex;
    std::cout << b << ": " // This line need to show me the pointer address but it 
    << *(b+=i)   << "   "  // output the value in linux 
    << *(b+=i+1) << "   "
    << *(b+=i+2) << "   "  // if i use &b it show me the address, but i remember that 
    << *(b+=i+3) << "   "  // for values not for pointers
    << std::endl;          // and *(b+=i) not change the address why?

}

return 0 ;
```

}

the out put is :

> a: a
> :    X   �
> :       B
> : X   �
> :    �
> : Y   �
> :       �   �
> ��: �
> :    @
> :
> : �
> : $   �   �
> : �
> : �   �
> :    �   �
> : �   �

i just want to print memory to the console in format of " Address: Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4 "

Comment: You're causing undefined behavior. Each system and compiler is allowed to behave differently. It's not specified in the standard how your program should behave. Your program could even erase your disk and order pizza.

Comment: `b` is only pointing at a single variable. Dereferencing `b+1`, `b+2`, etc is UB.

Comment: why do you expect incrementing `b` to have any meaning? What is the code supposed to do? It has ub on windows and linux btw

Comment: If you want adresses why are you dereferencing them?

Comment: see: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: "this line need to show me the pointer address" says who? It's a `char*`. The pointer should be pointing to a null-terminated character array, or the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: btw it is not clear what "Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4" should be in your ouput. You have a single `char` and one pointer to that, what are the 4 values you want to print?

Comment: @Quimby the format i want is " Address : val1 val2 val3 val4 "  i start with show the address and then show the values.

Comment: You are probably trying to do something like: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ISxaF4w6Bz9hmQJJ

Comment: just to see what values in this memory location

Comment: @underscore_d thenks it help

Comment: What bytes are in memory isn't actually useful to a majority of programmers, though, who really care about the numbers/strings/objects/whatever those bytes represent. And even if you had a clear statement of what you want this code to do, it isn't evident here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to do some like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
    char a {'a'};
    char* b { &a };
    std::cout << static_cast<void*>(b) << ": " << *b;
}

// Output: 0x7fff41d27787: a
```

You have to cast a char pointer otherwise `cout` will handle it as a C-string. Dereferencing `*(b + i)` causes undefined behavior for `i` > 0.